# upload windows phone 8.1 silverlight app in store after microsoft abandoned platform

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps, windows-10-mobile

I developed a wp 8.1 silverlight app now, in October 2017. I know it's really strange but is a company app that only its employees need to run.
I need a simple way to install the app inside every wp 8.1 and wp 10 devices this company has.

Until now i know i can connect the devices to my pc, deploy the app and works but i'm looking for a way to install the app without connect the device to my pc.

I can't upgrade the app to windows 10 universal because it has to run into wp 8.1 devices.

So, the question is: In October 2017, is it possible to upload a wp 8.1 silverlight app into the store? If the answer is no, is there another way to install app inside more devices without connect them to a pc?

Thanks for all

Answer (score 1):

> In October 2017, is it possible to upload a wp 8.1 silverlight app
>   into the store?

For wp 8.1 platform, Microsoft just will not provide any more new feature and update. You can still publish or update your Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 app.

The Dev Center package page still allows you to upload the .xap format package:
[image]

I have tested it and Dev Center still accepts .xap package. Just remember to change the publisher name and other identity info in package.manifest so that Dev Center could identify the package.